# Mysql PDO Wrapper that throws Unique Constraint Exception

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, pdo

The main reasoning behind this PDO wrapper, is that I find myself using unique constraints quite frequently in my designs, and I have `if ($ex->errorInfo[1] == 1062)` littered throughout my code, and I thought there has to be a better way.

```
<?php

class PDOMysql extends \PDO {

    public function __construct($dsn, $username = null, $passwd = null, $options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options);
        $this->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function prepareAndExecute($statement, array $params = []): \PDOStatement
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->prepare($statement);
            $stmt->execute($params);
            return $stmt;
        } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
            if ($ex->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
                throw new PDOMysqlUniqueConstraintException($ex);
            } else {
                throw $ex;
            }
        }
    }

}


class PDOMysqlUniqueConstraintException extends \PDOException {

    public function __construct(\PDOException $ex)
    {
        parent::__construct($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getCode(), $ex->getPrevious());
    }

}


// example usage 
$user = 'vps'; 
$pass = 'vps'; 
$db = new PDOMysql("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb", $user, $pass);

// create table 
$sql = "create table if not exists `mytable` (col1 varchar(100) null, constraint idx_u unique (col1) )";
$db->prepareAndExecute($sql);

// insert first row 

$params = ['col1' => uniqid('')]; 
$sql = "insert into mytable (col1) values (:col1)"; 
$db->prepareAndExecute($sql, $params);

// select row 
$sql = "select * from mytable where col1 = :col1"; 
$stmt = $db->prepareAndExecute($sql, $params); 
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());

// insert duplicate row 
try {
    $sql = "insert into mytable (col1) values (:col1)"; 
    $db->prepareAndExecute($sql, $params);
} catch (\PDOMysqlUniqueConstraintException $ex) {
   die('Unique Constraint Detected');
}
```

Comment: Do you run into this situation often ? Isn't is better to fix existing code to avoid the exception, rather than having to handle it ? Last but not least, is your exception class doing anything special that a generic, application-wide exception handler could not do ?

Comment: approx 15 uses in total across 5 projects. I was under the impression using the db constraint was the correct approach. Take for example users signing up, with a unique email address. I could go and select the user first to see if the email exists, but that would result in a race condition (however unlikely). I would like to be able to detect and handle that particular exception differently, which is why it isn't just a generic exception.

Comment: Database locks are meant to avoid race conditions. In Mysql you may want to use [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for example, at least if your tables are InnoDB.

Comment: I don't quite understand how SELECT FOR UPDATE would help in the case of inserting a user with a duplicate email address? If the email address doesn't exist in the db, there will be no row to select?

Comment: "For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries" So if there is a unique index, it gets locked and modification of the row or the index (range) is not possible until the transaction ends. And this applies even if there is no such row, the index entry is virtual, yet part of the locked index range.

Comment: @slepic I didn't know that, I will try it out, thanks

Comment: @Anonymous database locks are evil and you should avoid them when possible. The op has the correct approach to the problem and introduction table locks will make it much worse. Not to mention that there is no UPDATE query can be seen

Comment: What about a husband and wife who share a computer and an email account but want to login separately?

Comment: Use transactions to deal with race conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is so good that it's the first time I have nothing to say.

Your approach to the problem is absolutely correct and you should keep using it.

There could be only microscopic nuances, such as one mentioned by Sam. Or, the fact that your constructor would override the configuration settings passed in the $options array. Say, if someone would want to use FETCH_ASSOC as a default fetch mode, your class won't let them. I would rather make it this way

```
$defaults = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // I would throw in this one too
];
$options = array_merge($defaults,$options); 
parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $passwd, $options);
```

So this way you would have your preferred defaults that, however, could be overwritten, making your class flexible, without artificial restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

In [this presentation about cleaning up code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtB5DAfOWMQ) Rafael Dohms talks about many ways to keep code lean - like avoiding the `else` keyword. ([see the slides here](https://www.slideshare.net/rdohms/bettercode-phpbenelux212alternate/11-OC_1Only_one_indentation_level)).

It is wise to avoid the `else` keyword - especially when it isn't needed - e.g. when a previous block contains a `throw` statement - like in the `catch` section of the the method `PDOMysql::prepareAndExecute()`, there are two `throw` statements:

> ```
> if ($ex->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
>     throw new PDOMysqlUniqueConstraintException($ex);
> } else {
>     throw $ex;
> }
> ```